# Incorrect syntax near keyword "AND" SQL Server Update/Case statement

Tags: sql, syntax, case

Working on an update query with multiple joins and case statements. I keep getting the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'".

I have rearranged my join to avoid subqueries, but can't fix this issue.

Code:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.[FldrInit] = 
(CASE a.FldrInit
WHEN '889' AND d.GisCode LIKE 'HAP%' OR d.GisCode LIKE 'SAP%' THEN '889G1Pt'
WHEN '889' AND d.GisCode LIKE 'HAS%' OR d.GisCode LIKE 'SAS%' THEN '889G1Road'
WHEN '889' AND d.GisCode LIKE 'A????' THEN '889ProxixPt'
WHEN '889' AND d.gis LIKE 'R????' THEN '889ProxixRoad'
WHEN '883' THEN '883'
WHEN '885' THEN '885'
WHEN '886' THEN '886'
WHEN '887' THEN '887'
WHEN '900' THEN '900'
WHEN '902' THEN '902'
ELSE 'Other'
END)
FROM [dbo].[QCOrders_temp] as a 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[QCCloneOrders] as b 
ON b.NewOrdnum=a.OrdDte 
INNER JOIN [TOD].[dbo].[CurrentOrders] as c
ON c.Ordnum = b.OrigOrdnum
INNER JOIN [TOD].[dbo].[Addr] as d
ON d.RecNumAddr = c.RecNumAddr

WHERE a.FldrInit IS NULL
```

**EDIT**
@BhupeshC fixed the error, except now I'm getting a new one-- "Incorrect syntax near keyword 'END'". Any thoughts?

```
UPDATE a
SET a.[FldrInit] = 
CASE 
WHEN a.FldrInit = '889' AND d.GisCode LIKE 'HAS%' OR d.GisCode LIKE 'SAS%' THEN '889G1Road'
WHEN a.FldrInit = '889' AND d.GisCode LIKE 'A????' THEN '889ProxixPt'
WHEN a.FldrInit = '889' AND d.GisCode LIKE 'R????' THEN '889ProxixRoad'
WHEN a.FldrInit IN ('883', '885', '886', '887', '900', '902') THEN a.FldrInit
ELSE 'Other'
END
FROM [dbo].[QCOrders_temp] as a 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[QCCloneOrders] as b 
ON b.NewOrdnum=a.OrdDte 
INNER JOIN [TOD].[dbo].[CurrentOrders] as c
ON c.Ordnum = b.OrigOrdnum
INNER JOIN [TOD].[dbo].[Addr] as d
ON d.RecNumAddr = c.RecNumAddr

WHERE a.FldrInit IS NULL
```

Comment: that's an illegal abuse of the case syntax. `when` clauses must be VALUES. you're trying to convert those values into booleans. decisions should be made in the `case` clause.

Comment: I believe you're looking for alternative CASE syntax: `CASE WHEN a.FldrInit = '889' AND d.GisCode LIKE.... THEN...`

Comment: @MarcB - There are two forms, searched and simple. The first expects booleans, the second values. The OP has an illegal hybrid.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your `CASE` Statement with the following:-

```
CASE
WHEN a.FldrInit = '889' AND (d.GisCode LIKE 'HAP%' OR d.GisCode LIKE 'SAP%') THEN '889G1Pt'
WHEN a.FldrInit = '889' AND (d.GisCode LIKE 'HAS%' OR d.GisCode LIKE 'SAS%') THEN '889G1Road'
WHEN a.FldrInit = '889' AND d.GisCode LIKE 'A????' THEN '889ProxixPt'
WHEN a.FldrInit = '889' AND d.gis LIKE 'R????' THEN '889ProxixRoad'
WHEN a.FldrInit IN ('883','885','886', '887', '900', '902') THEN a.FldrInit
ELSE 'Other'
END
```

**EDIT**

The reason of the error is - your `case` statement has `a.FldrInit` as further checks. So you can't add multiple conditions on other columns. So you can use the mentioned syntax.

Comment: Probably those `OR` conditions should be parenthesised. `AND (d.GisCode LIKE 'HAP%' OR d.GisCode LIKE 'SAP%')` etc.

Comment: Also I'd simplify the 6 cases towards the end as `WHEN a.FldrInit IN ('883','885','886', '887', '900', '902') THEN a.FldrInit`